# Randomize elements of a list in jinja 2

Tags: python, sorting, random, jinja2

Is it possible to random sort a list in jinja 2?

Given a list like (1, 2, 3) get different results each run like:

```
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
.....
```

Comment: Do you want to display only one possible permutation or all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shuffle filter available, but it is easy enough to create one:

```
import random

def filter_shuffle(seq):
    try:
        result = list(seq)
        random.shuffle(result)
        return result
    except:
        return seq
```

which you'd then [register as a custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters):

```
environment.filters['shuffle'] = filter_shuffle
```

and use it as a filter:

```html
{% for elem in some_sequence|shuffle %}
    {{ elem }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, shuffle the list before passing it to the template.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random


@app.template_filter('shuffle')
def filter_shuffle(seq):
    try:
        result = list(seq)
        random.shuffle(result)
        return result
    except:
        return seq
```

Then in template

```
{% for option in list|shuffle  %}
```